# Access Error when logging into AWS Workmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workmail

My AWS workmail domain is something like this:

mydomain-com.awsapps.com

I created a user, but when I try to log in from a browser, I get the following error. I am able to get the emails on my iPhone though.

> Access Error This application has not been enabled for your directory.
> Please contact your Administrator for more details.

Answer (score 9):

My problem is I was using the wrong URL, should be:
https://mydomain-com.awsapps.com/mail

Answer (score 0):

I typed in https://{myalias}.awsapps.com under the assumption that it would be a single sign in for all services, but it actually redirected me to their workdocs product. You need to add the trailing "/mail" to the url to log in to just the email.